# ILM policy and template

Tags: indexing, logstash, kibana, ilm

Can I know whether can I use ilm template for my custom index. Will it rollover if yes to what value? My index is created in logstash. My index is indexname-team. Will it rollover using the template? What is the name?

Comment: You can use a Index Lifecycle Policy with your custom index, you need to create the policy and set it in the index template of your index. The documentation explains how you can do that, [take a look](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/set-up-lifecycle-policy.html).

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply I saw it earlier but I was confused. What will be the rollover name will it be my index name append with time? The document I could not understand. I have 20 index. What will be the rollover name? I want indexname-team-date in yyyyMmdd. How can it be achieved?

Comment: You need to explain better what you want to do, but using rollover you shouldn't use daily indices, you will let elasticsearch manage the index and use the alias to query and index.

Comment: Agreed I don't want daily index. But  I saw I can create my index without date at end. When it reaches rollover over size, it should use my index name append date.and rollover name should be same as index name

Answer (score 0):

The rollover happens base on the condition you have configured in the policy. The name of the roll over index would be incremented the integer as prefix of the index name.

For example, If your index name is sample-team, then below are the rollover indices.

```
sample-team-000001   // This is the initial index that you have created manually
sample-team-000002    // after first all other will be created automatic by policy
sample-team-000003
sample-team-000004
```

Reference: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/set-up-lifecycle-policy.html